# Ananconda, Windows, Python3.8 & python-barcode; intermittently get: [SpyderKernelApp] WARNING | No such comm:

Tags: python, crash, spyder, barcode

This is a bit of a puzzler...

It works, barcode .png files are generated, I can see and open the ones that do get made. But if the list of barcodes to make was 20 long, it would never complete without falling over.

```
from barcode import get_barcode_class
from barcode.writer import ImageWriter
import os

if __name__ == "__main__":

    dirName = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    tempDir = os.path.join(dirName, "TEMP")

    #Clear the TEMP area
    clearFolder(tempDir)   #Ignore this on Stackoverflow - this foo works - just here to note its not an overwrite problem

    #Get list of barcodes to gen
    lst1 = declareBarcodes1()
    lst3 = []
    options = {'compress':True, 
           'module_width':1.0, 
           'module_height':10.0, 
           'font_size':18, 
           'text_distance':1, 
           'quiet_zone':3,}

    bar_class = get_barcode_class('code128')
    writer = ImageWriter()

    for code in lst1:
    
        tempFile = tempDir + '\\' + code
        code128 = bar_class(code, writer)

        code128.save(tempFile, options)   #When stepping through manually, its this line that kills it
    
        tempFile = tempFile + ".png"
        lst3.append(tempFile)
```

The falling over appears to happen on the code128.save() line. Why is a mystery. It'll make 15 files OK on one run, then fall over without a file made on the next.

Console returns

[SpyderKernelApp] WARNING | No such comm:

With various large hex strings. i.e.

```
[SpyderKernelApp] WARNING | No such comm: f6502840ddad11eba4ad8cec4b464d5c
[SpyderKernelApp] WARNING | No such comm: 14acf428ddae11eb973d8cec4b464d5c
[SpyderKernelApp] WARNING | No such comm: 738e7abdddae11eb979f8cec4b464d5c
[SpyderKernelApp] WARNING | No such comm: 9cb2157fddae11ebb8348cec4b464d5c
```

Anyone got *any* ideas?!?

- Running with/without options dict makes no difference.
- I tried a time.sleep(5) in before the save line. Was arguably worse.
- I've tried different ways of calling to writer(), but it really does seems its the .save command thats doing it.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't quite an answer to the question I've posed - but using the svg writer part of py-barcode works without issues.

Need to use cairosvg to convert to png (for later use elsewhere) - but it works - after a fashion.

So if anyone happens to stumble across the exact same problem, then that's a workaround for them.